# Why does this char comparison cause errors?

Tags: c, debugging, char

In this function I am trying to check whether a char array contains a broadcast MAC address. I compare each array element with `0xFF` to do this.

```
static inline bool recibir_trama_l2_en_interface(interface_t *interface, cab_ethernet_t *cab_ethernet) {
    char *mac = MAC_IF(interface);
    if(IF_EN_MODO_L3(interface)) {
        char *mac_destino = cab_ethernet->mac_destino.dir_mac;
        mostrar_dir_mac(&interface->prop_intf->dir_mac);
        mostrar_dir_mac(&cab_ethernet->mac_destino);
        bool bandera_prueba = true;
        bandera_prueba = mac_destino[0] == 0xFF;            

        if(mac_destino[0] == 0xFF && mac_destino[1] == 0xFF && mac_destino[2] == 0xFF && mac_destino[3] == 0xFF && mac_destino[4] == 0xFF && mac_destino[5] == 0xFF) {
            printf("Esto está pasando.\n");
        }
        printf("AABBNINKD.\n");
        if(mac_destino[0] == 0xFF) {
            printf("Esto sí pasa.\n");
        }    
    }
    return false;
}
```

These are the structs that I am working with.

```
typedef struct cab_ethernet_ {
    dir_mac_t mac_destino;
    dir_mac_t mac_origen;
    short tipo;
    char payload[TAM_MAX_PAYLOAD];
    unsigned int FCS;
} cab_ethernet_t;

typedef struct dir_mac_ {
    char dir_mac[TAM_DIR_MAC];
} dir_mac_t;
```

The debugger shows me that the content of `mac_destino[0]` is `0xFF`. But you can also see that after the comparison, `bandera_prueba` is set to `false`.
[image]

Another thing that is happenning is that apparently the program is skipping these instructions.

```
if(mac_destino[0] == 0xFF && mac_destino[1] == 0xFF && mac_destino[2] == 0xFF && mac_destino[3] == 0xFF && mac_destino[4] == 0xFF && mac_destino[5] == 0xFF) {
    printf("Esto está pasando.\n");
}

if(mac_destino[0] == 0xFF) {
    printf("Esto sí pasa.\n");
}
```

I mean, the debugger jumps from line 78 to line 83 to line 89.
[image]
Is there something wrong with this kind of comparison that is causing these errors?

Comment: I think you probably want `struct dir_mac_ ` to use type `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the constant `0xFF` is 255. In your C implementation, `char` is signed and can only have the values −128 to +127. `mac_destino[0]` is a `char`. Therefore `mac_destino[0] == 0xFF` can never be true. Stepping through the code in the debugger appears to skip lines because the compiler has optimized the program to omit the impossible parts.

To fix this, change the type used to `unsigned char`.

Preferably, change the element type of `dir_mac` in `struct dir_mac_` to `unsigned char` and the type of `mac_destino` to `unsigned char *`. If you cannot do that, change the definition of `mac_destino` from `char *mac_destino = cab_ethernet->mac_destino.dir_mac;` to `unsigned char *mac_destino = (unsigned char *) cab_ethernet->mac_destino.dir_mac;`.

If you cannot do that, you can insert a conversion into each comparison, as by changing `mac_destino[0] == 0xFF` to `(unsigned char) mac_destino[0] == 0xFF`.